# Please help with adding sound to my website- on mouse-click

Tags: audio

I am trying to add sound to my web-site, when a link is clicked.
I added this javascript into the head of my doc:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function playSound('Swoosh 3-SoundBible.com-1573211927.wav') {
 document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
 "embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
 }
</script>
```

And I added this code into the body:
span id="dummy">

And this is what I added by the li that I want the sound to be heard on:
 onclick="playSound('Swoosh 3-SoundBible.com-1573211927.wav');

I got this from http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm. But this does NOT work when I tested it my browser. NO sound is heard on the mouse-click.
Can anyone help please?
Thank you!

Comment: it seems that you forgot to insert the left triangle bracket here ->  `innerHTML= "embed src=`. It must be `innerHTML= "<embed src=`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that the function knows what to make of "soundfile" because instead of naming the variable in your function header, you've replaced it with an explicit filename.  Try rewriting the function name as `function playSound(soundfile){}`.

Comment: Thank you Ray! That was my mistake! Thanks for your help.
One more thing: I have another menu that i would like to add sound to, except that this menu does not have a link to another page. Where then would I add the code to? Please check my site at www.trecall.com to see what I mean. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @suave design, this may not be what you are asking but you should be able to have something along the lines of `<a href="#" onclick="playsound();return false">` to create an anchor that will play a sound when clicked but does not lead to anywhere.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using the HTML5 audio element.
To make this work in as many browsers as possible, you should have an .mp3 and a .ogg version of your sound. 
For simplicity, I'm using jQuery to do the event handling.

The markup

```
<audio id='clicksound' style='display:none'>
<source src='mysound.ogg'>
<source src='mysound.mp3'>
</audio>
```

the JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.soundonclick').click(function(){
        document.getElementById('clicksound').play();
    });
});
```